# Outlook add-in with different behaviour between client desktop and web version when move mail to the junk folder

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm facing to an issue since several weeks now and I really need your help.

I'm currently developing an Outlook add-in in Javascript on Visual Studio Code generated with Yeoman (yo office) for my company that should move the mail to the junk folder when users click on the "Run" button on the taskpane.

The add-in works perfectly on the web version (OWA) when I click on the "Run" button but not on the desktop client. On the desktop client, it opens a new tab in my default browser (Chrome) and redirect me to the HTML file of my taskpane.

The add-in is hosted on Azure but on a storage account (".z6.web.core.windows.net/", not ".azurewebsites.com/") and the app is registered on Azure. In the application registration, I created two platforms, one for the web and one for the desktop version (native application) but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do so. The ID and access tokens are enabled for implicit and hybrid flows and it configured as a unique tenant. No public clients flows allowed.

I created a new project to show you my issue, this is the code :

```
import {UserAgentApplication} from "msal";
import {ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider} from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
import {MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions} from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";
import {Client} from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";

/* global document, Office */

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});

export async function run() {
  // Configuration Microsoft Graph 
  const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "<client-ID>",
      redirectUri: "https://synphishtest.z6.web.core.windows.net/",
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-ID>/",
      scopes : "user.read, mail.readwrite",
      loginType: "redirect"
    }
  };

  // Connect to MS Graph
  const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.readwrite"];
  const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);     
  const options = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(graphScopes);
  const authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(msalApplication,options);
  const MSALoptions = {authProvider};
  const client = Client.initWithMiddleware(MSALoptions);

  // Get the mail ID
  var idMail =  JSON.stringify(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId).replaceAll('/','-');
  const junkMail = {destinationId: 'junkemail'};

  // Move the mail to the junk folder
  (async () => { 
    await client.api('/me/messages/'+idMail+'/move').post(junkMail);
  })();

}
```

I'm using modules "msal" version 1.4.14 and "@microsoft/microsof-graph-client" version 2.2.1.

Since I have some difficulties to debug with VS Code, I'm using Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview to "debug" my add-in. When it opens a new tab on Chrome, I can see en Edge DevTools the following error : "Error opening popup window. This can happen if you are using IE or if popups are blocked in the browser". I don't use Internet Explorer and the popups are allowed on Chrome. I resolved this issue one time somehow but I don't remember how I did it.

And when I open the Chrome console on the new tab opened, I have the following warning : "Office.js is loaded outside of Office client". So on the desktop version, it opens a new tab and doesn't move my mail into the junk folder but on the web version, no new tab are opened and the mail is moved into the junk folder.

The tab is opened only when the program is here :

```
// Move the mail to the junk folder
  (async () => { 
    await client.api('/me/messages/'+idMail+'/move').post(junkMail);
  })();
```

Can you help me to make my add-in works on the desktop client ?
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: When you are making the post request can you check the response for success/error? Is there an error returned?

Comment: You may also try adding appropriate domains to the <appdomains> section of your manifest.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains

Comment: The problem is that the requests made from the desktop client and the web version are not the same as I can see on Fiddler.

Comment: In my manifest, there is 3 links added : my company website, my company's support portal website and the link to my add-in's taskpane (https://synphishtest.z6.web.core.windows.net/). I don't see why I should add another link in my manifest if it works on the web version.

Comment: What is different between the request made from the desktop client and the web version? Since you are running the same add-in I expect them to be mostly the same.

Comment: There are client differences between OWA and win32 when using certain APIs. You could be hitting this issue, so you might need to add the url in AppDomains for the win32 case.